# How do I use two versions of the same assembly inside an ASP.NET application?

Tags: c#, asp.net, dll, version, gac

I have an old version of an **asp.net** component. I would like to use a newer version alongside the old version.

I put both assemblies in the GAC using the `gacutil.exe` command. Now, I would like to load a specific version of the component inside each `.aspx` page.

How can I do this?

Can I use this code?

```
<%@ Register assembly="<dllname>, Version=2.5.0.0, Culture=neutral,
    PublicKeyToken=......." Namespace="<dllNamespace>." TagPrefix="WG" %>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use create an object of version you want in runtime using the following code

```
  Object obj = Activator.CreateInstance("dllName","dllNameSpace.ClassName");
```

you can refer to [Activator.CreateInstance](http://lozanotek.com/blog/archive/2006/03/22/8311.aspx) or [Use Activator.CreateInstance to Create Objects from a String Name](http://www.knowdotnet.com/articles/activator_createinstance.html)

Comment: That' s one of possible solution. But i want to use the library in aspx code. Because this dll contain asp control. Can i do similar think in aspx code ?

Comment: yes, just you created an instance of dll you want, you will use it as any object in your aspx page.

Answer (score 0):

Technicly yes, It's possible with the `Register` property you are asking about. It is however not a really easy path to walk as it will be riddled with strange limitations.

My suggestion would be to either not do it at all if possible or else isolate the controls of different versions in usercontrols that can live in separate class libraries. You'd get assembly names like: `controls_for_1_5` and `controls_for_2_5` and in here you create references to the assembly. (The names are of course for you to choose). This way can still cause strange errors like `Can't cast 'Namespace.ClassA' to 'Namespace.ClassA'`(Yes they are the same, it's not a typo) if your not carefull.

Still my advise would be to not do it unless you have a real strong understanding of the deeper parts of the .NET framework.

Comment: i not understood your solution. If i create two assembly, each with reference to specific dll, how can i add the library using Register command ? With register i have to add manually the assembly name and namespace, but two version have same name and namespace.

Comment: If you specify a version in your tag then .NET will look for that specific version in the GAC